# Add code into JS with button click

Tags: javascript, loops, audio

So I have these buttons that when pressed play a sound, and I wanted to make a button that when pressed would allow these sounds to loop. I dont know how to explain this correctly, so ill just show the code

```
function aud1play() {
  aud1.src = "aud1.mp3";
  aud1.play();
}
document.getElementById('aud1button').addEventListener('click', aud1play);

function aud2play() {
  aud2.src = "aud2.mp3";
  aud2.play();
}
document.getElementById('aud2button').addEventListener('click', aud2play);

function aud3play() {
  aud3.src = "aud3.mp3";
  aud3.play();
}
document.getElementById('aud3button').addEventListener('click', aud3play);
```

is there a way to take the names (aud1, aud2, aud3) and put (name).loop; under each of the functions with a button press without having to actually write the (name).loop; for every one?

Comment: do you wish to play all three audio's at one button click?

Comment: So basically what you are asking is how to detect when the sound is done playing and start another sound

Comment: You mean , you need to play a music associated to button continuously till the next button clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

JS:

```
function play(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
    audio.play();
}
```

HTML5:

```
<audio controls loop id="audio">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `bind` method: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/

```
function playAudio(type) {
   aud.src = (type === '1') ?
     "aud1.mp3" :
     (type === "2") ? 
     "aud2.mp3" :
     "aud3.mp3";

   aud.play();
}

document.getElementById('aud1button').addEventListener('click', playAudio.bind("1"));
document.getElementById('aud2button').addEventListener('click', playAudio.bind("2"));
document.getElementById('aud3button').addEventListener('click', playAudio.bind("3"));
```

Comment: this way, you can just reuse the audio player, and the `playAudio` function by passing in the filetype or filename using the `bind` function for each of the event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
// create an object containing all audio objects
var audios = (function () {
  var names = ['aud1.mp3', 'aud2.mp3', 'aud3.mp3'];
  var audios = {};

  for (var index in names) {
    var audio = audios[names[index]] = new Audio();
    audio.src = names[index];
  }

  return audios;
})();

function toggleAudioPlay () {
  // "this" refers to the button that was clicked
  var name = this.getAttribute('data-audio-src'); // read the button's "data-audio-src" attribute
  if (!audios.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    // audio doesn't exist
    return;
  }
  var audio = audios[name];
  audio.src = name;
  // toggle the play state
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
  }
}

function toggleAudioLoop () {
  var name = this.getAttribute('data-audio-src');
  if (!audios.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    // audio doesn't exist
    return;
  }
  var audio = audios[name];
  audio.loop = !audio.loop;
}

document.querySelector('.audio-button-toggle-play').forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', toggleAudioPlay);
});

document.querySelector('.audio-button-toggle-loop').forEach(function (button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', toggleAudioLoop);
});
```

Now, you could have the following HTML:

```
<button class="audio-button-toggle-play" data-audio-src="aud1.mp3">Play/Pause the first audio</button>
<button class="audio-button-toggle-play" data-audio-src="aud2.mp3">Play/Pause the second audio</button>
<button class="audio-button-toggle-play" data-audio-src="aud3.mp3">Play/Pause the third audio</button>
<button class="audio-button-toggle-loop" data-audio-src="aud1.mp3">Enable/Disable looping of the first audio</button>
<button class="audio-button-toggle-loop" data-audio-src="aud2.mp3">Enable/Disable looping of the second audio</button>
<button class="audio-button-toggle-loop" data-audio-src="aud3.mp3">Enable/Disable looping of the third audio</button>
```

That way, you don't have to create a new function for each audio. Just add a new audio file to the "names" array and add a button with a special class (`audio-button-toggle-play` in order to toggle the play state of an audio) and a `data-audio-src` attribute containing the location of the audio file.